# How to fix an issue with shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, string-literals

I'm working on writing code for simpliest shader.
Here is its code.

```
const char* Vertex_Shader_Descrip = "#version 330/n"

"layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;/n"

"void main()/n"
"{/n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);/n"
"}/0";
```

glsl shader compilation fails with the error

```
error C0206: invalid token "<invalid atom 199709744>" in version line
```

Don't remember the exact version of shader, but it supports opengl 3.3

Please, could you point on my mistakes if there's any or just explain me what is wrong?

Comment: `/n`? Shouldn't that be `\n`?

Comment: It seems you could need to spend some time to refresh basic C++ knowledge. The compiler will automatically add the null-terminator to all string literals, you don't need to add it yourself (it will just waste a character). And the wrong "newlines" is an indicator as well that you need to refresh your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reverse slash instead of used.

```
const char* Vertex_Shader_Descrip = "#version 330\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the `/n` and try adding `\n`.